# Como remover as informações de br do maps?

Tags: maps

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação wev de geolocalização de chuvas. No mapa quero apenas os pontos de captação de chuva. Contudo, o mapa padrão fornecido pela google fornece com informações de estradas (br's). Há como remover essas informações e deixar o mapa limpo?

Answer (score 2):

Isso consta na documentação do próprio Google Maps:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Veja um exemplo bem simples, com exemplos de mudança de cor, e com os nomes de estradas removidos (é só um exemplo, dá para customizar o mapa todo removendo ou estilizando cada uma das partes):

```js
function initialize() {
  var styles = [{
    stylers: [{
      hue: "#00ffe6"
    }, {
      saturation: -20
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [{
      lightness: 100
    }, {
      visibility: "simplified"
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [{
      visibility: "off"
    }]
  }];
  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
    name: "Styled Map"
  });
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.55, -46.633333),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEbOPG)**.

### Ferramenta para customização online:

Para evitar o trabalho de criar a configuração manualmente, tem uma ferramenta muito legal neste endereço para automatizar e fazer *preview* das configurações:

> http://instrument.github.io/styled-maps-wizard

Basta escolher elementos, configurar como quiser. Para configurar separadamente vários ítens, basta adicionar um ítem novo na barra da direita após customizar o atual. Cada ítem adicionado gera uma entrada no objeto de configuração.

Comment: Segue uma ferramenta para gerar a configuração já online: http://instrument.github.io/styled-maps-wizard/